# First record in PostgreSQL database not being read by PHP code

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with some information about projects contained with in it. So each project has a name, description and contact but I'm looking to just pull the **name** attribute from the table using PHP.

I currently have two projects in my database.

```
ID | Name |
1  | Fruit project |
2  | Vegetable project |
```

And I have a PHP script below which generates

```
$res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM projects");
$assoc = pg_fetch_assoc($res);
$result = $assoc['name'];

/* FETCHES THE RESULT OF THE SQL QUERY WHICH GETS THE NAME OF EACH PROJECT */
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $output[]=$row['name'];
    print (json_encode($output));
}  /* CONVERTED ON MOBILE PLATFORM */
```

But the output of that file is current 'Vegatable project'. Could any provide some help on why the script isn't producing the first result as well?

Comment: Why did you tag this with `Mysql`?

Comment: Was a suggested tag, sometimes experts can share their logical knowledge cross platform you know...

Answer (score 1):

Because you're stripping it out off the result before your loop:

```
$res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM projects");
$assoc = pg_fetch_assoc($res); // <-- remove
$result = $assoc['name'];      // <-- remove
```

Comment: That now reads the first record in the database but the output is `fruit, fruit, vegatable`. It reads it one too many times :P

Answer (score 0):

You call `pg_fetch_assoc` one time before the clycle - thet is the point where your first record is lost.
Just remove `$assoc = pg_fetch_assoc($res);`